# How do I set android:layout_columnWeight="1" programmatically to an element in an android support v7 Gridlayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to build a GirdLayout programmatically with 2 columns and I want these columns to have equal width set at half the width of the screen.

I figured out you can do this since API 21 or with the support v7 GirdLayout view. I see examples that uses android:layout_columnWeight="1" to do this. But I can not find how to do this programmatically.

Can anyone help me with this matter?

```
package com.tunify.v3.component;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.tunify.asme.data.ChangeableSelectionParameterValue;

public class ChangeableSelectionParameters extends GridLayout{

//private ArrayList<ChangeableSelectionParameterView> selectionParameterViews;
private ArrayList<ChangeableSelectionParameterValue> selectionParameterValues;

private static final int ITEM_PADDING_LEFT_DP = 0;
private static final int ITEM_PADDING_RIGHT_DP = 0;
private static final int ITEM_PADDING_TOP_DP = 0;
private static final int ITEM_PADDING_BOTTOM_DP = 0;

//private static final int MUSICCOLLECTION_DISPLAY_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 15;


public ChangeableSelectionParameters(android.content.Context context, ArrayList<ChangeableSelectionParameterValue> selectionParameterValues) {
    super(context);

    this.selectionParameterValues = selectionParameterValues;

    initializeLayoutBasics(context);
    initializeComponents();
}

private void initializeLayoutBasics(android.content.Context context) {
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    setColumnCount(2);
    setRowCount((int)Math.ceil(selectionParameterValues.size()/2.0));

    int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height);
    this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int paddingLeftPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ITEM_PADDING_LEFT_DP, metrics);
    int paddingRightPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ITEM_PADDING_RIGHT_DP, metrics);
    int paddingTopPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ITEM_PADDING_TOP_DP, metrics);
    int paddingBottomPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ITEM_PADDING_BOTTOM_DP, metrics);
    setPadding(paddingLeftPx, paddingTopPx, paddingRightPx, paddingBottomPx);

}

private void initializeComponents() {

    for(ChangeableSelectionParameterValue param : this.selectionParameterValues){
        ChangeableSelectionParameterView v = new ChangeableSelectionParameterView(getContext(), param);
        //TODO set views layout column weight to 1
        this.addView(v);
    }
 }
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
 GridLayout.LayoutParams parem = new LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),      GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
 v.setLayoutParams(parem);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found this method from GridLayout: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/GridLayout.java#GridLayout.spec%28int%2Cfloat%29

So maybe you could try something like this:

```
((GridLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams()).columnSpec =
    GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f);
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, I got an ClassCastException when I tried your code, but changed it a bit to get the answer. I added the solution to my question!

Answer (score 12):

-Here you are ! :>

```
Button button = new Button(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams param= new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(
            GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f));
param.height = 0;                                                                                                           
param.width = 0;
button.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using xamarin.android, these answers helped me, but I had to change the syntax a bit. So if anyone else is using xamarin.android here is the syntax:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.RowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
param.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
view.LayoutParameters = param;
```

Where `view` is the view contained in the GridLayout.

Comment: Does this work with a normal GridLayout or do I need to use `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`. Because I need to use my GridLayout in a ScrollView, but v7.widget is not allowed inside the ScrollView. But with my normal GridLayout, it is not working. Do I need to have set any other settings to the Layout ?

Answer (score 3):

This functions of GridLayout.Spec will allow you to set the weight correctly:

```
public static Spec spec(int start, int size, Alignment alignment, float weight)
public static Spec spec(int start, Alignment alignment, float weight)
public static Spec spec(int start, int size, float weight) 
public static Spec spec(int start, float weight)
```

usage example:

```
((LayoutParams) gm.getViewFromGridCoords(i, j).getLayoutParams()).columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(j, span, CENTER, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and tried lots of things.
My required design is as followings.
[image]

Finally, I solved this by following approach.

I add a grid layout to my xml file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridLayoutBillingInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2">
            </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I created a custom layout for each item in the grid layout. Only adding textview doesn't work but when put textview inside layout then it works.
See below -

```
 public class ItemLayout : LinearLayout {

  constructor(context: Context, text:String) :super(context){

    this.orientation = HORIZONTAL
    this.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL


    val param = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
        GridLayout.spec(
            GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f
        ),
        GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
    )
    param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    param.width = 0

    this.layoutParams = param

    var textView = TextView(context)
    textView.setText(text)

    this.addView(textView)

  }
}
```

finally add this item to grid layout with data.
See below -

```
   fun addDataToGridLayout{

    val gridLayoutBillingInfo = findViewById<GridLayout>(R.id.gridLayoutBillingInfo)

    val billDetailList : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    billDetailList.add("test data 1")
    billDetailList.add("test data 2")
    billDetailList.add("test data 3")
    billDetailList.add("test data 4")
    billDetailList.add("test data 5")
    billDetailList.add("test data 6")

    billDetailList.forEach {
      gridLayoutBillingInfo.addView(BillItemLayout(context,it))
        
   }
```

}

I hope it will help.